# Привязка Task<List<T>> к DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, асинхронность, task

Моя проблема заключается в том, что я пытаюсь привязать данные из Task<List> к DataGrid в своём WPF приложении, но я не понимаю в чем проблема и правильно ли я делаю привязку.

У меня есть 3 модели

DisciplineGroupTeacher:

```
public class DisciplineGroupTeacher
{
     [JsonPropertyName("iddiscipline-group-teacher")]
     public int IdDisciplineGroupTeacher { get; set; }
     [JsonPropertyName("idteacher")]
     public int? IdTeacher { get; set; }
     [JsonPropertyName("iddiscipline")]
     public int IdDiscipline { get; set; }
     [JsonPropertyName("idgroup")]
     public int IdGroup { get; set; }
     public async Task<Teacher> Teacher() => await DataWorker.GetTeacher(IdTeacher);
     public async Task<Group> Group() => await DataWorker.GetGroup(IdGroup);
     public async Task<Discipline> Discipline() => await DataWorker.GetDiscipline(IdDiscipline);
}
```

Teacher:

```
public class Teacher
{
    [JsonPropertyName("idteacher")]
    public int IdTeacher { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Group:

```
public class Group
{
    [JsonPropertyName("idgroup")]
    public int IdGroup { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("group_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("iddepartment")]
    public int IdDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Discipline:

```
public class Discipline
{
    [JsonPropertyName("iddiscipline")]
    public int IdDiscipline { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("discipline_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

В DataWorker у меня имеются методы для получения данных из API:

```
public class DataWorker
{
    public async static Task<List<DisciplineGroupTeacher>> GetDisciplineGroupTeachers()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync($"myurl...");
        var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<DisciplineGroupTeacher>>(await streamTask);
        return data;
    }
    public static async Task<Teacher> GetTeacher(int? id)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync($"myurl...");
        var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Teacher>(await streamTask);
        return data;
    }
    public static async Task<Discipline> GetDiscipline(int id)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync($"myurl...");
        var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Discipline>(await streamTask);
            return data;
    }
    public static async Task<Group> GetGroup(int id)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync($"myurl...");
        var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Group>(await streamTask);
        return data;
    }
}
```

При определенном событии я получаю BindingList в котором получаю List и устанавливаю его в ItemSource к своему DataGrid

```
BindingList<DisciplineGroupTeacher> dgts= new BindingList<DisciplineGroupTeacher>(await DataWorker.GetDisciplineGroupTeachers());
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = dgts;
```

В XAML я делаю Binding

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDatGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="13">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="Discipline" Binding="{Binding Discipline.Name}"/>
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="Group"  Binding="{Binding Group.Name}"/>
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Header="Teacher"  Binding="{Binding Teacher.Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Но при запуске у меня не появляются в датагрид нужные мне поля. Что я делаю не так? С async await познакомился недавно. До этого приложение работало с локальной БД, но сейчас нужно получать данные из API.

Comment: Task - это задача. Задача по получению данных. Это не сами данные, это задача по их получению. Привязывать надо к данным, а не к какому то левому классу типа задачи. Получите данные, потом привязывайте.

Comment: @tym32167 Я не понимаю как мне в модели получать данные другой модели. Я пытался сделать так
public Teacher Teacher => await GetTeacher();
public async Task<Teacher> GetTeacher() => await DataWorker.GetTeacher(IdTeacher);
но это тоже не работает, всегда возвращается нужно добавлять Task

Comment: Вместо `BindingList` лучше использовать `ObservableCollection`. Не надо создавать `HttpClient` на каждый запрос, создайте его один раз `private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();`. И вы не показали метод `GetDisciplineGroupTeachers`. Ну и самое главное - привязка возмождна только к публичным свойствам. К методам привязаться невозможно.

Comment: Вот это почитайте: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding На будущее, пост можно редактировать, не надо создавать дубликаты - кнопка **Править**.

Comment: @aepot Добавил GetDisciplineGroupTeachers. Спасибо, сейчас почитаю

Comment: @aepot Не получается. Сделал как по документации в ссылке. Скопировал класс TaskCompletion, но убрал INotifyPropertyChanged. Создал правильно свойства. Поля получаю так:
Teacher _Teacher => new TaskCompletion<Teacher>(DataWorker.GetTeacher(IdTeacher)).Result;
Но всё равно не отображается результат в datagrid.
Я много искал про привязку именно как в моём случае, асинхронность в wpf, но ничего не получается найти.

Comment: Если все сделали правильно, должно работать.

Comment: @aepot Я взял из документации класс NotifyTaskCompletion, убрал из него INotifyPropertyChanged, так как я не использую MVVM. После я пытаюсь получить данные что то типо `private Teacher _Teacher => new TaskCompletion<Teacher>(DataWorker.GetTeacher(IdTeacher)).Result;`  И свойства: `public Teacher Teacher{get{return _Teacher;}}`

Comment: @aepot У меня кст приложение не на MVVM. Может быть без него у меня не получается? Просто никогда не практиковал MVVM, и слишком много нужно будет переделать.

Comment: Ну это же ваше приложение, вам и решать, как его лучше писать. Если речь о WPF, я вообще не представляю, как без MVVM можно что-то вменяемое под него писать. Когда я впервые узнал про MVVM и привязки, и взялся переписывать, мне пришлось выкинуть примерно половину кода как лишний хлам. И это с учетом, что всех полезных приемов, доступных в WPF я тогда еще не знал. У вас много повторяющегося кода - это индикатор проблем. Хотя-бы вот метод `public static Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(int id) => client.GetFromJsonAsync<T>($"myurl...");` заменит всё что у вас в классе `DataWorker` - учите обобщения.

Comment: @aepot Хорошо, спасибо большое.